# Data not updating at the expected time in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application that lists out data from a server in a view that looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr ng-repeat="query in saved_queries">
    <td ng-click="fill()"><a>{{ query.query_string }}</a></td>
    <td class="pull-right" ng-click="kill_entry({{query.id}})"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The saved_queries object is populated from a button with an id "refresh" that runs a function called refreshSubmit() from this controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('QueryCtrl', ['$scope', 'Query', function ($scope, Query) {
     $scope.kill_entry = function(id){
        var kill = $.post('http://my_ip:3000/api/delete_query', {'id': id});
        kill.done(function(result){
            $('#refresh').click();
        });
     }
     $scope.refreshSubmit = function(){
       var savedQueries = $.post('http://my_ip:3000/api/saved_queries');
       savedQueries.done(function(result){
          $scope.saved_queries = result;
        })
      }
      $scope.saveSubmit = function() {
        var save_query = $.post('http://my_ip:3000/api/save_query', { 'query_string': $scope.query_box });
        save_query.done(function(result){
            $('#refresh').click();
     });
   }
  }
])
```

The problem is, I have to click the "refresh" button TWICE in order for the data in the view to update after a record has been created or destroyed.

Ideally, it would only need to be clicked once.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Don't use JQuery for ajax calls in Angular. Use the `$http` service anf Angular will update view on request completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen not to follow the AngularJS philosophy fully, which is fine - that's your choice. But in choosing to use jQuery's $.post() mechanism instead of Angular's $http mechanism, you are skipping a step it would normally do for you. Add a

```
$scope.$apply();
```

call in your `$.post()` result callbacks and your data will update immediately. AngularJS requires this as a trigger to know when model data may have changed and it should look at it (it would be super inefficient to just constantly poll every data object it tracks). Alternatively, you could do the same thing with `$http` and not need the above step.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $http service which will trigger a $digest cycle and update your view.
I would call the refreshSubmit method directly instead of using jquery to trigger the click event.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('QueryCtrl', ['$scope', 'Query', '$http', function ($scope, Query, $http) {
     $scope.kill_entry = function(id){
        var kill = $http.post('http://my_ip:3000/api/delete_query', {'id': id});
        kill.success(function(result){
            $scope.refreshSubmit();
        });
     }
     $scope.refreshSubmit = function(){
       var savedQueries = $http.post('http://my_ip:3000/api/saved_queries');
       savedQueries.success(function(result){
          $scope.saved_queries = result;
        })
      }
      $scope.saveSubmit = function() {
        var save_query = $http.post('http://my_ip:3000/api/save_query', { 'query_string': $scope.query_box });
        save_query.success(function(result){
            $scope.refreshSubmit();
     });
   }
  }
])
```

It would also be better to move the $http requests to a factory. That makes it easier to test the controller and a better separation of concerns.